# Facebook Javascript SDK Send Invites to a 'Page' rather than an 'Application'

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Page set up in Facebook, and I'm being asked to provide functionality to invite other users to come to the page.  I know I can send a request for applications via the FB.ui method, but is there any way to provide the same functionality for a page?  I've tried the FB.ui method as described on the developer site, but it's quite reasonably taking me to the App URL (we have both set up).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Apologies.  Should have said this is set up as a Canvas app (not what we want the invites to be for, as to access, they have to like the page) and as a Page Tab (which is where we want them to go to, so they can like the page and then access the app content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just redirect the user to the page tab when they land on your canvas page (having accepted the request)?

Comment: Yeah.  Looks like that's my only alternative at the mo.

Comment: I think this is intentional, requests are supposed to drive traffic back to canvas apps, i think any other use of them will require workarounds like this unless the requests API changes